# Convert from duration ( HH-MM-SS) to minutes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I want to convert from duration ( HH-MM-SS) to minutes, but the result return only correct when duration of hour < 24 hour with function HOUR(). Otherwise result is not correct.

Anyone can help?

below is link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w4DksMyaJbJQd3Sp3fsBPACTc1u14SOXObZUKXC1j38/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

By one side, durations as well as dates are handled by Google Sheets as serialized numbers, by the other side, HOUR treats it's argument as a date.

The unit for dates, including durations, is 1 day. To get the hours divide the duration by 24.

Answer (score 0):

Edited your file, this is the formula:

> =INT(B2)*60*60+(B2-INT(B2))*24*60